# Hight And With Requirement For Uploader

Tags: php, file-upload

I currently have created this script.

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    $path = "/path/to/file";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path."/".$_SESSION['Username'].".png");

    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
   }
?>
```

I wish to specify a maximum high and width for the image uploaded. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the PHP function `getimagesize();`

The getimagesize() function does not require the GD library.

Try this:

```
<?php
    // Set maximum width and height in pixels
    $maxwidth = 4000;
    $maxheight = 4000;

    $allowedExts = array("png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
        // List the width, height, image type, img attributes of the uploaded file into the specified variables
        list($imgwidth, $imgheight, $imgtype, $imgattr) = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

        // If the image is too wide, or if the image is too tall, don't upload and tell the user.
        if($imgwidth < $maxwidth || $imgheight < $maxheight){
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
                echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

                $path = "/path/to/file";
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path."/".$_SESSION['Username'].".png");

            }
        }else{
            echo "File width or height is too large.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
?>
```